# Backup gem confused with openafs-client

Tags: ruby, rbenv

I am following a [walk-through](http://backup.github.io/backup/v4/installation/) to get started with the Ruby Backup gem.

I ran `gem install backup` which worked fine, but then when I tried to run:

```
backup generate:model --trigger my_backup \
--archives --storages='local' --compressor='gzip' --notifiers='mail'
```

and I get the error message:

```
The program 'backup' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install openafs-client
```

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04.

Any idea what my problem is or how to fix it?

UPDATE:
 - Ruby Version: `ruby 2.1.6p336 (2015-04-13 revision 50298) [x86_64-linux]`
 - Using rbenv

```
echo $PATH
/usr/local/heroku/bin:/home/stoebelj/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build/bin:/home/stoebelj/.rbenv/shims:/home/stoebelj/.rbenv/bin:/home/stoebelj/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build/bin:/home/stoebelj/.rbenv/shims:/home/stoebelj/.rbenv/bin:/home/stoebelj/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build/bin:/home/stoebelj/.rbenv/shims:/home/stoebelj/.rbenv/bin:/home/stoebelj/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build/bin:/home/stoebelj/.rbenv/shims:/home/stoebelj/.rbenv/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/db/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin:/home/stoebelj/.rvm/bin:/home/stoebelj/.rvm/bin
```

Comment: What is your ruby version? What does `backup version` print?

Comment: How ruby is installed (rvm/rbenv/some packages/etc)? What is your `echo $PATH`?

Comment: answers given in update.